# Creation of LAN flash game with Java

Tags: java, flash

At my high school, many students in my friend group play the "Super Smash Flash" game. When playing with multiple people, out best solution is to play with multiple keyboards connected to the same computer. Unfortunately, there are only so many keys on a keyboard which means some players are forced to play with a less than optimal control set up. To fix this problem, I want to implement a program that does the following:

- Shows the same graphical display to the user, shelling the game executable for easy updating.
- Uses a network protocol to transmit keystrokes to one or multiple user defined subnet IP address(es).
- Receives keystrokes from the other computer(s) and sends the keystrokes to the program, changed based on the incoming IP address.
- Keeps all instances of the game synced.

Honestly, I have no clue where to start, being fairly novice at java, but any and all help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is about an entire project, and not really suitable for SO. If your main question is about getting started, you'll need to start doing some reading into java's standard APIs  that are used for this stuff.

The API you'll probably want to use for the GUI / keyboard is Swing:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Network code / syncing will probably revolve around the socket API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Would you happen to know where I would learn to shell the flash game? Thanks, and I'll be more specific in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too much about flash. But good luck on your project!